# X-Axis in matlab freqz command

Tags: matlab, frequency

I want to see the frequency response of a DC notch filter.

If I run the following code:

```
a = [1 , -0.99]; b = [1,-1];
y = filtfilt(b,a,x);

freqz(xcorr(b,b),xcorr(a,a))
```

The following output is returned:

[image: pic1]

I'm confused by the meaning of the x-axis, (normalised frequency (×π rad/sample)).
Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalized frequency relates to the nyquist frequency.

On the x scale;

1 = Nyqist frequency = sampling rate/2